# Questions relating to other Questions

Tags: discussion

Is it Ok to ask questions which relate to other questions?

Take this as an example

[First Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786407/ul-list-not-scrolling-on-key-press-but-it-does-with-mouse-wheel)

[Second Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839270/div-and-unordered-list-scroll/22839691)

The OP did not receive an answer to the First Question and decided to open a new broader question.

Or should the Bounty system be used in this case like suggested 
[image]

Comment: I failed to see that the first question is unanswered. On the othrler hand, I might flag the second one as unclear without working code (I didn't since I'm not an expert in HTML though)

Comment: @AndrewT. The first question was unanswered *at the time the second question was posted*.  It has since gotten answers.

Comment: I'm not convinced it is a duplicate but the relationship between 2nd and the 1st one is not clear to me. So I've voted to close as unclear.

Comment: @AndrewT. for people who know html better it is easy to see where the asker is lagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it Ok to ask questions which relate to other questions?

The way it is being done here, I would say no. That is precisely what the bounty system is for. They are asking, as you said, a more general question to get an answer on the first question. The OP should be edited to add any more detail or clarification they can to try and get more views/answers. Also, there were answers on that post so if those don't work then the OP should comment and say so. This is likely to produce feedback which might very well lead to an answer.

### When it is ok to refer to another question

This would be ok if the OP asked a question, got an acceptable answer but had a somewhat related but different question. Then linking to the original (related) question would be fine.

**Or** if the person found a similar question by someone else but the answers didn't quite give the results needed then linking to that question would be fine, possibly helpful, and encouraged.

The way I see it, the second question in your post is a duplicate (less helpful and less clear) of the first question.

**Edit**

I did *just* notice that the answers on the first post were posted slightly after the second question but I still believe it shouldn't be done this way and that the second post is a dupe.

Comment: Ah, Nice answer :)